# Logs Pulling Architecture

Tags: elasticsearch, logging, logstash, filebeat

Filebeat uses a "push" architecture, sending logs to logstash or elastic. Is there a feature or product that would enable elastic to receive hosts' logs using a "pull" architecture?

In my setup, I have network connectivity only from my elasticsearch cluster to the hosts I would like to collect the logs from, so I can't use the default log shipping architecture of filebeat or fluentbit.

Thanks!

Comment: Pulling implies polling and it's not really ideal for log management use cases as logs can usually be generated all the time and it would be hard for your polling component to keep up in case of peak loads, whereas in the usual push architectures, the side that pushes logs can handle backpressure (Logstash, Filebeat do that) in case the sink doesn't keep up.